# Appropriate implementation of function cv.glmnet from glmnet R package regarding binary categorical outcome

Tags: r, feature-selection, glmnet, glmmlasso

I would like to use the `cv.glmnet()` function, in a microarray dataset to perform some kind of "feature selection/variable importance" and prioritize with this way, the selected features with the lasso approach (which coefficients are different than zero). My outcome is a categorical binary outcome (factor, 2 levels). My specific questions are the following:

1) Which **measure of loss** would be more appropriate? `type.measure="mse"` or `type.measure="class"`, concerning the fact that essentially the suited model here is a binomial logistic regression? (based on my type of outcome)?

2) To use the function `coef()` at the end, which lambda value for `alpha=1` is more valid? That is, `lambda.min` or `lambda.1se`?

3) As the function runs "internally" the `glmnet()` function, ***also the features here are scaled by default*** (`standardize=TRUE` argument in the `glmnet() function`)?

Comment: What is the question for #3?

Comment: If the features in cv.glmnet are scalled also by default ?